# In Idris, how to show that a non-trivial equality is Refl?

Tags: equality, dependent-type, idris

I'm building a little dependently-typed lambda calculus interpreter:

```
import Data.Vect

%default total

{- fin helper functions and lemmas -}

incrFin : Fin n -> Fin (S n) -> Fin (S n)
incrFin x FZ = FS x
incrFin FZ (FS y) = FZ
incrFin (FS x) (FS y) = FS (incrFin x y)

subrFin : (x : Fin (S n)) -> (y : Fin (S n)) -> (x = y -> Void) -> Fin n
subrFin FZ FZ neq = absurd (neq Refl)
subrFin FZ (FS x) neq = x
subrFin {n = S n} (FS x) FZ neq = FZ
subrFin {n = S n} (FS x) (FS y) neq = FS (subrFin x y (\Refl => neq Refl))

indexOfIncrFin : (x : Fin (S n)) -> (y : Fin n) -> (env : Vect n a) -> (t : a) ->
  index (incrFin y x) (insertAt x t env) = index y env
{- elided -}

indexOfSubrFin : {n : Nat} -> {env : Vect n a} -> (neq : (x = y) -> Void) ->
  index (subrFin x y neq) env = index y (insertAt x t2 env)
{- elided -}

indexInsertAt : (x : Fin (S n)) -> (t : a) -> (env : Vect n a) -> index x (insertAt x t env) = t
{- elided -}

incrFinChanges : (x : Fin n) -> (y : Fin (S n)) -> Not (incrFin x y = y)
{- elided -}

{- main code -}

data Ty = Base | Arrow Ty Ty

data Expr : Vect n Ty -> Ty -> Type where
  Var : (x : Fin n) -> index x env = t -> Expr env t
  Con : Expr env Base
  App : Expr env (Arrow t1 t2) -> Expr env t1 -> Expr env t2
  Abs : (t1 : Ty) -> Expr (t1 :: env) t2 -> Expr env (Arrow t1 t2)

incr : (x : Fin (S n)) -> (tt : Ty) -> Expr env t -> Expr (insertAt x tt env) t
incr x tt (Var y Refl) {env = env} = Var (incrFin y x) (indexOfIncrFin x y env tt)
incr x tt Con = Con
incr x tt (App e1 e2) = App (incr x tt e1) (incr x tt e2)
incr x tt (Abs t1 e) = Abs t1 (incr (FS x) tt e)

subst : (x : Fin (S n)) -> Expr env t' -> Expr (insertAt x t' env) t -> Expr env t
subst {env = env} {t' = t'} x e' (Var y pf) with (decEq x y)
  subst {env = env} {t' = t'} x e' (Var x Refl) | Yes Refl = rewrite indexInsertAt x t' env in e'
  subst {env = env} {t' = t'} x e' (Var y Refl) | No neq = Var (subrFin x y neq) (indexOfSubrFin neq)
subst x e' Con = Con
subst x e' (App e1 e2) = App (subst x e' e1) (subst x e' e2)
subst x e' (Abs t1 e) = Abs t1 (subst (FS x) (incr FZ t1 e') e)

substIncr : (x : Fin (S n)) -> (e' : Expr env t') -> (e : Expr env t) -> subst x e' (incr x t' e) = e
substIncr x e' (Var y Refl) with (decEq x (incrFin y x))
  substIncr x e' (Var y Refl) | Yes eq = absurd (incrFinChanges y x (sym eq))
  substIncr x e' (Var y Refl) | No neq = ?substIncr_missingCase
substIncr x e' Con = Refl
substIncr x e' (App e1 e2) = rewrite substIncr x e' e1 in rewrite substIncr x e' e2 in Refl
substIncr x e' (Abs t1 e) = rewrite substIncr (FS x) (incr FZ t1 e') e in Refl
```

The problem is the last missing case of the `substIncr` proof. The type won't reduce, because `subst` only reduces when the proof in Var is identically `Refl`, and instead it's `indexOfIncrFin x y env t'`. Now, indexOfIncrFin is total, it always returns Refl, but its type isn't just `f x y = z`; it, instead, has a complicated term on either side of the equality (`index (incrFin y x) (insertAt x t env) = index y env`). So when I try to match on it, via `with` or `case`, it complains about "type mismatch between `index y env = index y env` (type of Refl) and `index (incrFin y x) (insertAt x t' env) = index y env` (expected type)."

The only other thing I could think of was to change the definition of `subst` to rewrite instead of matching on `Refl`, but that (a) is kinda uglier, and (b) bogs me down in some kind of `rewrite__impl` type I understand even less, and which also won't reduce.

Any ideas on how to work around this?

Comment: This is why you typically have an inductive type for `Var` which specifies what it means for a variable to have a given type in a given context rather than relying on the result of a computation.

Comment: @gallais I already moved it from `Var : (x : Fin n) -> Expr env (index x env)` to `Var : (x : Fin n) -> index x env = t -> Expr env t` for exactly the same reason, but I'm a little uncertain what the inductive type you're suggesting as a further improvement would look like.

Comment: [Something like this](http://lpaste.net/355652)

Comment: Ah, that's clever. Thanks a lot!